# Angular http.get() returns array with data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Color } from '../model/color';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ColorService {
  private productsUrl = 'http://localhost:5500/colors/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getColors(): Observable<Color[]> {
    var colors = this.http.get<Color[]>(this.productsUrl + "all");
    
    return colors;
  }
}
```

and a component that gets the result of this method:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.colorsService.getColors()
      .subscribe((colors) => {
        this.colors = Object.values(colors);
        this.colors.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        console.log(colors);
      }, err => {
        this.displaySpinner = false;
      }, () => {
        this.displaySpinner = false;
      });
}
```

My `Color` interface looks like this:

```
export interface Color {
    id: number;
    number: string;
    name: string;
    imagePath: string;
    category: string;
    color: string;
    brand: string;
}
```

Now when I do this `console.log` in the component, it gives me an array named `colors`, with as a child another array with the actual data:

```
{
  colors: [
    {
      id: 1,
      number: 159,
      name: 'glamorous peach',
      imagePath: '/src/assets/img/colors/color104.jpeg',
      category: 'summer',
      color: 'orange',
      brand: 'Pink Gellac'
    }
  ]
}
```

I seem to recall that this was not the case in a previous version of angular, and when I do something like the below in the HTML page, it is unable to get the `color.name`, I think because of the array nesting happening here:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let color of colors">
    <mat-card class="example-card"
        style="width: 95%; border-radius:15px; box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);">
        <mat-card-content>
            <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="250">
                <mat-grid-tile class="tile" style="overflow:auto;">
                  <div class="wrapper">
                    <p>{{color.name}}</p>
                  </div>
                </mat-grid-tile>
              </mat-grid-list>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Any idea of how to work around this? Because of the typing in the service (`Color[]`), I seem to be unable to manipulate this array into what I need for the `ngFor` to work.

Comment: does this work?  Object.values(colors[0]);

Comment: No, ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is coming from the API, you just need to set it differently for it to work! Access the colors array and set it to the variable!

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.colorsService.getColors()
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.colors = <Array<Color>>response.colors;
          this.colors.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        }, err => {
          this.displaySpinner = false;
        }, () => {
          this.displaySpinner = false;
        });
  }
```

Comment: And as what do I type the observable in the service, now I get Property 'colors' does not exist on type 'Color[]'

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your component code to extract the colors array from the response before assigning it to this.colors.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.colorsService.getColors()
    .subscribe((response) => {
      // Extract the colors array from the response
      const colorsArray = response.colors;

      // Sort and assign the colors array to this.colors
      this.colors = colorsArray.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

      console.log(this.colors);
    }, err => {
      this.displaySpinner = false;
    }, () => {
      this.displaySpinner = false;
    });
}
```

```html
<!--  HTML template, you can iterate over this.colors directly: -->
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let color of colors">
  <mat-card class="example-card" style="width: 95%; border-radius:15px; box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);">
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="250">
        <mat-grid-tile class="tile" style="overflow:auto;">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <p>{{color.name}}</p>
          </div>
        </mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: In the service, what is the type of this response? because now I get Property 'colors' does not exist on type 'Color[]'

Comment: In your service, you are specifying the return type of the getColors method as Observable<Color[]>, indicating that it returns an observable of an array of Color objects.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can transform the Observable value to retrieve the `colors` array via [`map` RxJS operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map).

```
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ColorService {
  ...

  getColors(): Observable<Color[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(this.productsUrl + 'all')
      .pipe(map((resp: any) => resp.colors as Color[]));
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3qx8av?file=src%2Fcolor.service.ts)